# How to correlate two columns on excel

Tags: excel, data-analysis

On my Excel worksheet, my 1st column I have 150 ID's of persons who attend to an event. Since I have 5 more columns of ID's (some of different dimensions) is it possible to see if an ID who was present on the 1st event (column 1) was on the remaining events (column 2 to 6)?
I've already tryed the funtion 'CORREL' but shows '#N/A'.

Comment: Post few of your sample data then show your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

This formula sums a participant in all the other columns, and if it is equal to the count of events show YES other NO and the value of the presence on the remaining events.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B$2:F$8,$A3)=5,"YES","NO("&COUNTIF(B$2:F$8,$A3)&")")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use an easy formula and use that as an input for conditional formatting, as you can see here:

[image: Excel screenshot]

This is based on the following formula:

```
=MATCH(B1;$A$1:$A$5;0)>0
```

As you can see, I check for every cell if it matches one of the entries in column `$A` (the dollar-sign is needed to ensure the searched range does not shift).